# refer to "x" by "y" or refer to "x" as "y"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality, sentence-structure

How to correctly use refer to:

> We refer to products prior to "x" by "y"

Or,

> We refer to products prior to "x" as "y"

Comment: We refer to gizmolators prior to model 725 **as** "obsolete".

Comment: to refer to something by the term [widget]|to refer to something as [widgets].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to one thing ***as*** something, that is a term, label or characteristic that you say it has. It is a label that is applied to it.

> I'd prefer you **refer to me as** Vice-Chancellor.
>   In the expression x/y, we **refer to y as** the *divisor*.
>   It might be an old lean-to, but the owners **refer to it as** the conservatory.

If you refer to one thing ***by*** something, that is the *type* of label you apply. You are identifying the label, rather than actually using it.

> In the House of Commons, we must **refer to one another by** constituency.
>   I'd prefer if you **refer to me by** my title.
>   These rooms **are referred to by** use.